# Android license status unknown without Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-licenses

I wanted to install flutter without Android Studio. So, I installed Android SDK manually. And when I have run "sdkmanager --licenses" and the result:

```
~$ sdkmanager --licenses
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...             
All SDK package licenses accepted.
```

after that I run "flutter doctor -v". The result:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-40-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at /home/nisa/Android/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (6 days ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/nisa/Android
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.
```

So I run this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. And it says:

```
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that
the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

I have installed cmdline-tools but why still got that error? I have watched or read tutorials on how to solve this problem but all of them use Android Studio, not manually installed like mine.

Want to solve the "Android license status unknown" problem and get Flutter installed on my pc without Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Error says `Android Studio` has not `cmdline-tools` SDK tool. You need to install it.

- Go to Android Studio Setting.
- Navigate to Android SDK.
- Go to SDK Tools Tab.

You will find `Android SDK Command-line Tools` Install It and try again this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. But what I'm trying to do here is installing flutter without installing android studio.